# Wrap two adjacent td's

Tags: css, html-table, responsive-design

I have a table with two columns, both 300px wide, taking 600px in width on a regular computer screen.

I want to modify the display of that table for small screen mobile devices.

Is there a CSS way to make the cell of the right column to wrap and go below the cell of the left column, followed by the next left cell, followed by the next right cell, and so on?

Comment: Are you actually using `<table><tr><td>...` mark-up? How many rows in you table? Can you post your HTML?

Comment: google for media queries

Comment: You could probably do this with divs, tables really should just be used for tabular data

Comment: It is tabular data indeed.

Comment: @Sven, could you please instruct me how do I wrap that table for a media query for iPhone 4S, for example?

Comment: @Marc, about a dozen rows, two columns, <table><tr><td> etc. Standard two-column HTML table.

Comment: @DimitriVorontzov when you want it specific for that phone, then you need to know the screen width of that device. Then you make a css rule like this: `@media only screen and (max-device-width: XXXpx)` where XXX stands for the screen width of you Iphone

Comment: I understand that, @Sven - thank you! - but my actual question is: what CSS should I put between the { } to make the table wrap?

Comment: Targeting a specific device via media queries is a very poor way to go about it.  (see: http://designshack.net/articles/css/responsive-design-why-youre-doing-it-wrong/ and http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a proof-of-concept demonstration.

Consider the following table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>First Row - Cell 1</td>
        <td>First Row - Cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Second Row - Cell 1</td>
        <td>Second Row - Cell 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you float the table cells, you can get them to stack vertically, for example:

```
table {
    width: auto;
}
table td {
    background-color: lightgray;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

You need to adjust the table width and the cell width in your media query.

The one advantage of using floats is that the table is responsive without using media queries, which may be useful in some instances.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/qSd7g/

Answer (score 3):

A table is just like any other HTML element.  If you don't like the way it is displaying, you change its display property.

```
table, tbody, tr, th, td { display: block }
thead { display: none } /* optional */
```

Demo for reformatting a complex table: http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/ukBqo

Comment: Except that this does not work on IE 9 and older, though this is probably not relevant here.

Comment: Media queries don't work in IE8 and older anyway, but it certainly works in IE9.

Comment: Thank you, @cinnamon, I needed to know this. It's definitely most helpful, in the long run.

Comment: It’s the code presented in the question that does not work on IE 9 and older. Those versions have built-in table formatting routines, so setting `display` on table-related elements is ineffective.

Comment: Thank you, @Jukka. I was asking this question so that I can write CSS for small screen devices. They don't have IE9, to the best of my knowledge. I very much appreciate your pointing this out though, it's very useful in the context of the bigger picture (pun intended).

Answer (score 1):

You need to be using `media queries` to change the CSS properties dependant on screen size or browser width.

To target iPhone 5 in portrait mode you could do something like this:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
    td {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

To target a more general array of devies you would use a more general query to catch more screen sizes:

```
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 800px)  {
    td {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/94zQg/) (resize the browser window)

There is a great resource for iPhone / iPad related media queries [HERE](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/#iPhone)

Comment: Why `min-device-width : 320px` ?

Comment: Because the minimum width an iPhone 5 screen will ever be (ie. in portrait mode) will be 320px. This ensures that you are only targeting iPhone 5 or a device with the exact same dimensions. If you want a more general query you would omit the the min-device-width and orientation and just use max-device-width

Comment: Thank you! I am just getting used to media queries so your comments were instructive.

Comment: I fail to see the logic here.  You're restricting reformatting tables to devices that are >= 320px wide and in portrait mode, so anything smaller than that or in landscape mode gets the normal table formatting?

Comment: @cimmanon I was illustrating how to target a specific device. There is a more general example directly beneath it.

Comment: Thank you, @3rror404! Great example and a lot of useful info!

Comment: @3rror404 Except for the fact that it's an extremely awful way to use media queries.  There's no good reason to do it that way.  Either the device is wide enough to support the element in question as is or its not.  Media queries aren't for feature detection.  http://designshack.net/articles/css/responsive-design-why-youre-doing-it-wrong/