# Responsive Tables - Allow one row to take up multiple lines

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, html-table

Currently, on a desktop my table looks like this:

```
__________________________
| FoobarFoo | Foo  | Bar  |
| BarfooBar | Foo  | Bar  |
---------------------------
```

When a user is browsing from a small screen, I'd like the table to be like this:

```
____________
| FoobarFoo |
| Foo | Bar |
| BarfooBar |
| Foo | Bar |
-------------
```

Currently, it cuts off at foobar. I'm using a standard table.

Comment: Are you against using twitter bootstrap?

Comment: There have been experiments with responsive tables, such as this one: http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrap two adjacent td's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461150/wrap-two-adjacent-tds)

Comment: I am already using Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

@gladsocc, you can do this with JQuery very easily. Please find below link for same..
I am not sure whether it'll be helpful to you or not. I just want you to try this way.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_tables_reflow

More ways to make tables responsive:

http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_tables.asp

Thanks!